# How to reuse an ngTemplate which wraps a Viewchild that updates it's content

Tags: typescript, angular7, viewchild, ng-template

I want to reuse an ng-template with a viewchild that changes dynamically and have it update in all the places I reuse the ng-template. However it doesnt update in all places.

It works when i make the content of the ng-template static like this:

```
<h2>Position 1</h2>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="statusTemplate"></ng-container>
<h2>Position 2</h2>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="statusTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-template #statusTemplate>
  <h3>Saved</h3>
</ng-template>
```

that outputs the following HTML:

[image]

However when i make the `h3` inside the ng-template a view child and try to update it dynamically it doesn't update in both places.

e.g.

```
<h2>Position 1</h2>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="statusTemplate"></ng-container>
<h2>Position 2</h2>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="statusTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-template #statusTemplate>
  <h3 #status></h3>
</ng-template>
```

then i have this code dynically set the inner content of the view child, however the update doesnt appear in both places i re-use the template

```
@ViewChild('status', { static: false })
public status: any;

public setStatusTo(name: string): void {
  this.status.nativeElement.innerHTML = name;
}
```

The html looks like this when it runs in the browser

```
  <h2 _ngcontent-rdv-c3="">Position 1</h2>
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
  }-->
  <h3 _ngcontent-rdv-c3="">Success</h3>
  <h2 _ngcontent-rdv-c3="">Position 2</h2>
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
  }-->
  <h3 _ngcontent-rdv-c3=""></h3><!---->
```

[image]

How can i achieve updating the reused ng-template in multiple places? Why doesnt this work?

Comment: I think better solution is use  component instead  `<h3 #status><h3>` and  create  some  ReplaySubject to pass  value

Comment: this is a simplified example, can you make a working example of what you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do it this way (it seems easier to save the contents of h3 in a variable and then simply binding it) but if you want to take that approach, I would use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren('status')
  public statusElements: any;

  public setStatusTo(name: string): void {
    this.statusElements.toArray().forEach(
      (status) => {
        status.nativeElement.innerHTML = name;
      }
    ) 
  }
}
```

You can see the entire thing working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af19ma

Comment: For the record: before I was accessing directly this.statusElements._results but it's actually "cleaner" to use the toArray() method so that we don't access private properties. Both should work though.

Answer (score 0):

So like alternative you can  add into your component:

```
public status$: ReplaySubject<string> = new ReplaySubject();
```

and then use it instead `h3`

```
{{status$ | async}}
```

In case if you need to pass  html   depending on status you can create component which will do it according status.

```
<status-viewer [status]="status$ | async"><status-viewer>
```

Comment: I have used an async ReplaySubject for the set value and when i reuse the ngTemplate it is still not updating in all places. Only the first one. So this solution doesn't work.

Comment: So  my bad. I think instead of `ng-template`  you can use just component  and it will work.

Comment: no prob, thanks for the effort. unfortunately my actual set up is more complicated, this is just a simplified example for the question.I had to use view child and ng template. The issue that is happening is that the viewchild selector only updates and selects 1 view child but the ngtemplate reuseses it so there is more than 1 and they don't all get updated.